# Move line that matches pattern to top of file (multiple files)

Tags: awk, sed, files, email

I've got a folder containing roughly 4000 text files, each of which contains an email and its headers. I want to convert all the files in the folder to one `.mbox` file, but to do that I need every email to have the `From` header as the first line of the file.

I figure to do this I need to use something like `awk` or `sed` but I have no idea how. Does anyone have any suggestions or guides that would allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: Does the "From" line need to be *moved* or *copied* ? Can you give a small sample input and output?

Comment: This will need some refinement, but how about something like this: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -n 1 -I FIL bash -c 'printf "From \n" && cat FIL' >../allemails.mbox`

Comment: @JeffSchaller It needs to be moved - if you imagine a load of email headers, the "From" header needs to be moved from wherever it is in the file to top of the file so it is the first line (the first header).

Comment: I believe that the Mbox format uses a line starting `From ` (note the space) to signify the start of a new email, but the `From: ...` header is fine where it is. Try the above line and see if the resulting file works in your email program.

Comment: @bitinerant Mail (default Mac program) accepted the file but seems to have lost about 600 messages. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @Nothe - Not sure, but perhaps some emails don't end in newline, so try: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -n 1 -I FIL bash -c 'printf "\nFrom \n" && cat FIL' >../allemails.mbox`

Comment: @bitinerant Same number of emails with that. Interestingly it seems only emails that have something of substance after the "From " show up in Mail. Unsure if that's simply an Apple quirk or an actual standard.

Comment: It feel as if there should already be a tool out there that does email message manipulations like these.  [`formail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/formail) (part of the `procmail` distribution) does this, if I remember correctly. Not writing this as an answer as I don't have `formail` installed and no good test data to run it on.

Comment: @Nothe - Sorry you're still missing ~600 emails. [How To Convert EML File To Mbox ...](https://vsubhash.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/how-to-convert-eml-file-to-mbox-format-in-linux-and-import-it-into-thunderbird-and-seamonkey/) discusses this conversion and provides a Bash script which should produce a file very similar to my `find ...` above. Yes, there should be tried-and-true tools to do this (in addition to `formail`). What OS are you on and can you install new packages?

Answer (score 0):

To have email id as header or first line of the file, use below command to achieve the same:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt"  -exec sed  '1i emailid' {} \;
```

Above command will insert email id as first line of every file whose format of file is .txt.

Comment: I believe you're misunderstood the OP: "I need every email to have the From header as the first line of the file." not the string "emailid"

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the files and [use ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html). The `ed` command would be:

```
ed -s input <<< $'/^From .*@/m0\nw\nq'
```

This edits the file named `input` in script-mode (`-s`) to suppress printing of the bytes when we save & exit. The here-string `<<< $' ... '` sends commands to `ed` on its stdin. Those commands instruct ed to find the line where that starts with the string `From` followed by anything, followed by an `@`; on that line, execute the `m`ove command and put it after line zero -- make it the new first line. Then `w`rite the file back to disk and `q`uit.

All that remains is to loop over the files with some shell wildcard and `for` loop; for example:

```sh
for file in ./*.txt
do
  ed -s "$file" <<< $'/^From .*@/m0\nw\nq'
done
```

This edits your files in-place, so work on a backup copy until you're happy with the results.

You may tighten the regular expression search pattern `/^From .*@/` if your data supports it; perhaps by adding requirements for a date string to exist or for a certain number of sub-domains to exist in the email address, etc.

For further information on `ed`, install it and run `man ed` or `info ed`; or check the [online man page for ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html).

Comment: Note that unless the email messages are saved in such a way that any line that is _not_ a proper `From` header is escaped appropriately, this may do "interesting" things, for example in a message including another message with headers in its body.

Comment: Maybe make it stop when it sees the empty line that delimits header from body? But then again, `ed` is not a stream parser...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kusalananda, managed to get it working (finally) using `formail`.

```
cat `find . -type f -name '*' -print` | formail -es > ../result.mbox
```

Comment: `find . -type f -exec cat {} + | formail -es > ../result.mbox` is better. `-name '*'` is a no-op and you should never use a command substitution like that as it would break at the first file/directory that contains a space in its name.